# How can I define categories for Hints?

Tags: bixby

In the `capsule-info.bxb` file, you can define [Hints](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/hints) as suggested phrases to use with Bixby. There is a key within the `hints` element called [`for-category`](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/hints.for-category) that lets you assign different phrases to different categories, but I don't know how to define them. Any help?

**Current Code**

```
hints {
  uncategorized {
    utterance (What should I wear today?)
    utterance (Do I need an umbrella?)
    utterance (What is the weather in (San Diego)[v:viv.geo.SearchTerm]?)
    utterance (Change my units to Celsius.)
    utterance (Change my sentence to Detailed.)
  }
}
```

I'd love to be able to add a category for asking about the weather and categories for changing settings.

Answer (score 0):

Categories are still under development. You will know which categories you can use once they are released. Please watch out for the official announcement!